# PHP POST API no file received

Tags: php, api, curl, post

Our team is working on developing a web application for accessing a 3D printer remotely in PHP. We tried implementing the POST print_job part using the multipart/form-data but it doesn't work, which shows no file received. This API would check id and key. Here is the code. Any help is appreciated!

It's running on Apache 2.4.39, PHP 7.3.5, XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.2.

The details are:

```
<?php
function callAPI($method, $url, $data){
  $curl = curl_init();

  switch ($method){
     case "POST":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        if ($data)
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        break;
     case "PUT":
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
        if ($data)
           curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                               
        break;
     default:
        if ($data)
           $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
  }
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


  // EXECUTE:
  $result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
  curl_close($curl);
  return $result;
}
?>



<?php
include('api.php');

$_SESSION['ip'] = "";
$_SESSION['url'] = "http://".$_SESSION['ip']."/api/v1";

$target_dir = "../uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file); 
$filedata = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
echo $target_file;
$data_array =  array(
  "jobname" => "file",
  "file" => "new \CURLFile(realpath($filedata))"
);
$_SESSION['size'] = $_FILES['file']['size'];
//$make_call = callAPI('POST', $_SESSION['url']."/print_job", $data_array);
$response = callAPI('POST', $_SESSION['url']."/print_job", $data_array);
$_SESSION['print'] = $response;
header('location: ../index.php');
?>
```

Ps: If I want to upload the file which was got from front-end to the remote API, I may have to store it locally. Then I tried it as the following code. It works.

```
file_put_contents("E:/xyz/test.gcode",file_get_contents("../uploads/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$filedata='E:/xyz/test.gcode';
if(!is_readable(realpath($filedata))){throw new \RuntimeException("upload file not readable!");}

$data_array =  array(
  'jobname' => 'file',
  'file' => new \CURLFile($filedata)
);
```

Comment: Which part is "showing no files received" ? If the PHP script isn't seeing them (ie, no `$_FILES` etc) then check the file size - the default max upload is only 1mb IIRC.  You may need to tweak your `php.ini` and restart the webserver

Comment: The .gcode file size should be ok, it's only 166kb. I think the way I define $filedata would be wrong. But I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: Try `print_r($_FILES["file"])`  - make sure the  error code is `0`, that you have a temp file name, the user's name for the file, and a file size, etc.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. The error is 0, and the `[type] => application/octet-stream`

Comment: This is very poor: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`

Answer (score 0):

first off, don't set the `Content-Type:multipart/form-data` header manually because you'll corrupt the boundary if you do. the full header looks something like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------777d48028c332f50
```

so remove this:

```
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data");
```

and let curl set it for you. (curl will automatically set that header, with the correct boundary, when setting CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to array.)

second, you're not sending an actual file here, you're just sending the literal string

```
new \CURLFile(realpath($filedata))
```

.. if you want to send the file pointed to by $filedata , do

```
$data_array =  array(
  "jobname" => "test",
  "file" => new \CURLFile(realpath($filedata))
);
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! For the first part, do I need to remove  enctype="multipart/form-data" in the code under the picture of POST API?

Comment: @sxj1121 nah, the HTML tags are ok, they just instruct the web browser to use the `multipart/form-data` format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just went to the lab and tried it. But it turns out to show "Connection Failure" which I didn't see before. Does that mean I didn't connect to the API?

Comment: @sxj1121 could be, depends what the problem is. replace
```$result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}```
 with
```$result = curl_exec($curl);
  if(!$result){throw new \RuntimeException("curl_exec error ".curl_errno($curl).": ".curl_error($curl));}```
- what do you get now?

Comment: It shows: uploaded../uploads/p1.gcode
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: curl_exec error 26: in E:\xampp\htdocs\3dprinter\server\api.php:55 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\3dprinter\server\print.php(19): callAPI('POST', 'http://128.194....', Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\3dprinter\server\api.php on line 55 I am checking these code

Comment: the print.php(19) is $response = callAPI('POST', $_SESSION['url']."/print_job", $data_array);

Comment: @sxj1121 curl error 26 means it couldn't open a file, probably that file you tried to post. add before the exec ```if(!is_readable(realpath($filedata))){throw new \RuntimeException("upload file not readable!");}```, what do you get now?

Comment: I added it after `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
$filedata = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];` in my print.php. Then it shows `Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: upload file not readable! in E:\xampp\htdocs\3dprinter\server\print.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\3dprinter\server\print.php on line 11`